# Make a content provider act like a service and stay active when app closed in Xamarin Forms - Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have created a custom document provider for Android using this code as a base.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/storageprovider/

This works well, other than when I close the app it stops the content provider from working.

Is it possible to have the content provider act like a service, so that when you close the app the content provider is still there to use?

If so are there any Xamarin Forms examples on how to do this?

Comment: Your `ContentProvider` is instanced on-depend by the OS and is available whether the app containing the `ContentProvider` is actively running or not. What are you trying to achieve by "keeping it running".

Comment: It needs to be logged into the service to be able to get the drives, so I was wanting it to prompt for the login the first time it open, but then always be showing after that until it needs to prompt for a password again, however currently when I close the app it shuts down and hides the drives in the view?  Are you saying this shouldn't be the case and they should stay there even after the app is closed?

Comment: Your `ContentProvider` provider needs to be independent of the rest of your app. Maybe that means it needs to read saved login creds (i.e. `EncryptedSharedPreferences`), etc.. but the `ContentProvider` class that you are writing needs to be independent so the OS can instanced it when needed without your app running

Comment: I have the same problem. The content provider works well while the app is active and running. When the app containing the content provider is closed, the cursor returned by ContendResolver.query() is always null. Debug console says "Failed to find provider info for com.company.sampleapp.provider". Did you solve this issue?